# How to create named ranges dynamically?

Tags: excel, list, dynamic, range

I'm trying to create dynamic ranges that will scale dynamically, but this is proving tough to do.  The idea is to create two drop-down lists.  The first will populate dynamically based on how many columns you have in the first row.  If you have 10 column headers, you get 10 options.  If you add 3,  you now have 13 options from the dropdown, etc.

The next step is to then populate another list based on what you chose in the first.  So, if I selected the option that is the header for column 3, I want to be able to select only the options from column 3.  If I chose from the first list the header that corresponds to column 5, I get all values in column 5, etc.

I've looked at named ranges, and have been successful in creating a dynamic range to populate the headers in the first list, but I'm a bit perplexed about how to reference the correct column in the 2nd.

Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Debra Dalgleish's [Contextures](http://www.contextures.com/xldataval02.html) site. She's got lots of good material on dependent lists, including dynamic ones.

Comment: I already have, but it is not explained how this can be done.  I would like to create a new range when a new column is created, but it doesn't apppear that this can be done.

Comment: I don't have time to work on it right now, but I would use the WorkSheet_Change event:  Trap any changes in Row 1, and when they occur: 1. Refresh the first data validation (I think you already are) and 2. Delete and recreate the set of dynamic ranges from the columns that have values in Row 1.